# Get window handle of calling window

Tags: c#, dll, window, handle

there is a software which calls a method in my C# dll. In this dll method i need to have the window handle of the program/window which called my dll.

how to get this "calling window handle"?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the method called? Can you add an `hwnd` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can return the main window handle.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
```

As i know there is no way to get a concrete window because it's no more than Form object.
But Form class has a property `Handle`. You can pass it as an argument to dll method calls.

Comment: thats the problem, I can't pass an argument to my dll method from source program. so i cant pass the handle. i need to find out the handle within my dll method

Comment: Hmmm... Unfortunately the only way to solve a problem is to rewrite dll a little. I see no troubles here (if both dll and executable are written by you so you have sources) except the design of assembly will suffer...

Comment: yeah i implemeted the code you told me, this works. don't have sources of calling program, so i had to use GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle. i think there is no other "clean" way?

Comment: Yes, i can't imagine another solution. Another methods will be probabalistic so they're not a choice.

Comment: Years later, but I am running into the same issue, I am creating an application with plugins and one need to create a windows message hook from the dll and I cannot get the main applications handle for the life of me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't: windows don't call methods, code calls methods.

You should ideally add a window handle parameter to your method. If that's absolutely impossible, you could use, say, the `GetActiveWindow` API function to get the window active on the current thread. This isn't guaranteed to work; maybe there are no windows open.

What do you need the window handle for?

Comment: to modify calling window, currently i use GetForegroundWindow but this is not really a good solution, so if user is changing window immediatelly i will have the wrong handle